# Solr 6.5.1 - programmatically manage synonyms

Tags: solr

I want to use synonyms for my search.
So I defined a 'synonyms' *fieldType* in *schema.xml*.

```
<fieldType name="foo" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="german" />
    <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" managed="german" />-->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This *fieldType* is used by a field:

```
<field name="test" type="foo" required="true" />
```

Now I am adding synonyms to Solr (6.5.1) via the API, like this I can keep the synonyms updated via a web backend, e.g.

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '["mad","angry","insane"]}' "http://localhost:8983/solr/core/schema/analysis/synonyms/german"
```

That's pretty cool and adding works as expected.
I can see them through:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core/schema/analysis/synonyms/german

My problem is that this needs re-indexing, before they work, even though I am using query-time instead of index-time.

Is it possible to manage the synonyms "on the fly" without re-indexing?

My impression is, yes, as long as I am using query-time, but this is not working for me, so I guess I did something wrong?

Do I have to use synonyms.txt over the API to achive this?

But the text file would not as easy as the API to maintain the synonyms I guess?

Thanks for reading and best regards

Answer (score 2):

As described in documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources#ManagedResources-ApplyingChanges:

> Changes made to managed resources via this REST API are not applied to
>   the active Solr components until the Solr collection (or Solr core in
>   single server mode) is reloaded.

So you don't need to reindex data to see new synonyms in query-time. You just need to reload core with https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-RELOAD or https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-RELOAD:ReloadaCollection

Take a note that you should reload all cores in your solr setup. If you have two cores and reload only one, you will see changes only on one reloaded core.